# Why would two Excel cells that appear to have the same values test as not matching?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm creating a validation column for a worksheet. I've attached an image of what's going on.

- Column A contains an indexing function and works properly. The formula appears at the bottom of the image.
- Column B is hardcoded with the index values--no functions--cut-and-pasted from external File #2. This column will be used as a lookup column to bring additional data into the original document.
- Column C compares the values in A/B and conditionally formats the cell. In the event that a line may be missing from one of the two files, we have a quick visual reference of where the lists fall out of sync so we may correct the error.
- Column D is returning unexpected results, as you can see in the attached image.

Here are the things I have verified:

- The worksheet has about 3000 lines and 40 columns. I've worked with much larger files before without incident.
- Cols ABDF are formatted `Number>Special>0000.00`
- Col CC, noted in the formula for AB, contains the number 2 or the number 3. I tried re-calculating after changing the number format from `general` to `Number>Special>0000.00`
- Cols ABDF have been expanded to about 20 decimal places, and I did not spot a lonely .000000000001 in any of the values.
- I've refreshed my data so everything re-calculates as current.
- Cols D & F were created as tests just to see if could take the values and compare them and get different results. I did not get different results; my test appears on the uploaded image.
- And yes, I did a cold reboot and started Excel all over again. :)

[image]

Any ideas or hints what's going on or where to look for how to correct it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try comparing the values as text strings:

`=IF(TEXT(E364,"0000.00")=TEXT(F364,"0000.00"),"OK","Danger Will Robinson!")`

Alternatively, there may be a precision issue with the imported data from external file. IN which case, you can change your test:

`=IF(Abs(E364-F364)<0.00001,"OK","Danger Will Robinson!")`

The second option assumes that you can safely treat numbers that are 0.00001 difference as "equal". If not, just bump out the decimal places in that equation up to a max of I think 15 digits.

Comment: Here's what I found with my data. The calulated value is `0067.1000000000001000000000000000000`, the hardcoded value is `0067.1000000000000000000000000000000`, and `ABS(E-F)` comes out to `0000.0000000000000568434188608080000`. Of course, this completely baffles me...how can math involving ONLY whole numbers and hundreths calculate a gazillionth? And why is the difference between the two not making sense? Are there inherent math issues in excel that I'm not aware of?

Comment: both of your suggestions worked flawlessly, by the way... :)

Comment: This is caused by the way Excel stores numbers and calculates with them - using "floating-point arithmetic" - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113 - the normal method for working around is to use ROUND, using TEXT effectively achieves the same as rounding

Comment: Glad those options work for you! the formula you entered is not ONLY using the hundredths, it's using the full cell value, which is merely **displayed** to the hundredths place. Note that applying number formatting does **not** alter the value stored in the cell, it merely masks how that value is displayed to the user.